# How do you evaluate this summation: $S=\sum\limits_{r=0}^{15} (-1)^r \frac{\binom{15}{r}}{\binom{r+3}{r}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients, contest-math

Find S:
$$S=\sum_{r=0}^{15} (-1)^r \frac{\binom{15}{r}}{\binom{r+3}{r}}$$

---

**My attempt:**

I tried writing the summation as:

$$S=3!(15!)\sum_{r=0}^{15} (-1)^r \frac{1}{(15-r)!(r+3)!}$$

and tried to convert it to a telescoping form, but to no avail.

---

I don't know how to go about solving this question and any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$S=\sum_{r=0}^{15} (-1)^r \frac{\binom{15}{r}}{\binom{r+3}{r}} = \sum_{r=0}^{15} (-1)^r \frac{15!}{r! (15-r)!} \frac{3!\cdot r!}{(r+3)!}$$
$$= 15!\cdot3!\cdot\sum_{m=3}^{18} (-1)^{m+1} \frac{1}{(18-m)!} \frac{1}{(m)!}$$
$$= \frac{3!}{16 \cdot 17 \cdot 18} \sum_{m=3}^{18} (-1)^{m+1} \binom{18}{m}$$
$$= \frac{3!}{16 \cdot 17 \cdot 18} \left( \left(- \sum_{m=0}^{18} (-1)^{m} \binom{18}{m} \right) + 1 - \binom{18}{1} + \binom{18}{2} \right) $$

Now since
$$\sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i \binom{n}{i} = 0 $$
it becomes
$$= \frac{3!}{16 \cdot 17 \cdot 18} \left( 1 - \binom{18}{1} + \binom{18}{2} \right) = \frac{1}{6}$$